# My selenium webdriver hangs (freezes) at some point of my project

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The project works till a specific point where there its just freezing...

this is where it stops:

```
private def doActions(purchaseInfo: PurchaseInfo) = {
    driver.get(baseUrl)
    val addPur: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.id(addPurchLinkLocator))
    addPur.click()
```

this is happening:

```
    driver.get(baseUrl)
```

but         `addPur.click()` is not happening and the browser is just hanging..

iv tried all the solutions in stackoverflow where they tell you to upgrade selenium or downgrade firefox....im stuck :/

Comment: I don't know what language this is, but it isn't Java.

Comment: this is scala, its running on the jvm so I thisnk its relevant

Comment: So put Scala tag. Java isn't really relevant here.

Comment: You don't need to up/downgrade anything, but you do need to say what's happening during the pageload. Most likely a request is hanging. Have you tried this outside of Selenium?

Comment: @Guy are you the tag police?

Comment: @JohnBigs, if we can see what's going on during the 'freeze' then we might be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

Try by Add Explicit wait statement after driver.get(baseUrl) till addPurchLinkLocator element is visible,Because page load might take time.

Comment: How does that answer the question? Please clarify how this addresses the apparent hanging.